# How to uninstall programs in ubuntu if they are not in Software Center? 12.04

Tags: 12.04, software-center, uninstall, software-installation

I've installed a program through the terminal, the program is Cuttlefish.
Now I want to uninstall it and  I can't find it in the software Center.

How can I do it?

Comment: How did you install the program?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can uninstall the program through the terminal, very much like how you installed it.

Run `sudo apt-get remove --purge <package-name>`

So for cuttlefish you would run `sudo apt-get remove --purge cuttlefish`

Answer (score 7):

install synaptic package manager. Go to terminal by **clrt+alt+T** and type

`sudo apt-get install synaptic`

Form this you can install and remove packages in ubuntu without software center. Have a nice time.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get purge cuttlefish
```

Instead of uninstall, it removes anything related (most of the time).